# Can you get a rank worse than B in VVVVVV time trials?

Tags: achievements, vvvvvv

Time trial mode gives ranks to runs. I made a pretty bad run and got... a B, which isn't that bad of a mark? I was expecting a big bold F or something.

[image]

Is B the worst rank VVVVVV will give?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, B is the worst rank. The possible ranks are

B (lowest)
A
S
V (highest)

From [a VVVVVV wiki](http://vvvvvv-wiki.wikispaces.com/Play+Modes):

> In the Time Trials play mode [...] **The objectives are finishing the level in less than the par time, collecting all the trinkets, and avoiding deaths**. [...] **If none of these objectives are met during a time trials run, the player is awarded a "B" rank. If some of the objectives is met the player receives a higher rank: "A" rank for one objective met, "S" rank for two objectives met, and "V" rank for all three.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I've heard of grade inflation, but this is just silly.